# How can I change the fields of a struct's json marshal?

Tags: go, struct, go-gorm

**tl;dr**

How can I dynamize the JSON fields of a struct?

I am using [gorm](http://gorm.io) as the ORM. I have my model definition as a struct:

```golang
type UserAccessToken struct {
    Id        uint           `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"-"`
    CreatedAt time.Time      `json:"createdAt"`
    DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `json:"deletedAt"`
    User      User           `gorm:"constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE" json:"-"`
    UserId    uint           `gorm:"not null" json:"-"`
    IpAddress string         `gorm:"not null" json:"ipAddress"`
    Token     string         `gorm:"not null" json:"token"`
}
```

I have multiple endpoints and I want to use different fields of the struct serialized on each endpoint.

For example, on `POST /user-access-tokens/` user will be basic authenticated and a new access token will be created and returned on the response. However, on `GET /user-access-tokens/` list API endpoint, the response will be a list of the `UserAccessToken`s, but the `Token` won't be on the response. And I am planning to create another endpoint only to be used by the administration interface, and all fields will be available there.

There are two I can think of:

1. Creating a different struct and reading from the database into this struct.
2. Adding a method like `Map(scenario string)` to the model struct which will create a map of the struct according to scenario, but in this case, I also need to add function to handle multiple instances of the struct.

What is the recommended way for this?

Comment: Hi Gokhan, knowing more about your application can yield better answers. 
What are these two endpoints doing? How are they called? How complicated application are you building (lines of code / amount of layers / packages?)

Comment: Hi Tomor, you are right, I updated my question and added example use cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another struct:

```
type UserAccessstruct {
    Id        uint           `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"-"`
    CreatedAt time.Time      `json:"createdAt"`
    DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `json:"deletedAt"`
    User      User           `gorm:"constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE" json:"-"`
    UserId    uint           `gorm:"not null" json:"-"`
    IpAddress string         `gorm:"not null" json:"ipAddress"`
   
}


type UserAccessToken {
    UserAccessstruct
    Token     string         `gorm:"not null" json:"token"`
}

func Get() {
   var userAccess UserAccessToken
   db.Select(selectQuery).First(&userAccess)
   

   return userAccess // Full return
   return userAccess.UserAccessstruct // Inner struct without token
}
```

Comment: This would get interesting if there are more than 2 cases right? Like `UserAccessTokenBase`, `UserAccessTokenAdmin`, `UserAccessTokenIgnore` etc. 

Comment: not necessarily, you will have to decide between coping the struct and maintain both or use this kind of solution.